# Unity Android Cardboard SDK screen dims

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-sdk-tools, google-cardboard

Hi I'm following the Google IO tutorial:
https://io2015codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/cardboard-unity

everything works fine but the screen seems to dim. How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Could you post some code where you think the problem might be? It sounds more like a hardware problem.

Comment: It dims somewhat, or the screen turns off? In any case, `Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;` may resolve your issue, but do provide us with further details please.

Comment: I'm not sure what can I provide, I literally just followed the step in the above example. The only thing i had to do different was, I'm running a device with no external storage. So I set the setting of storage to force internal because it was failing to install on device otherwise. Using Samsung S5